# How to create a spinner with rectangular box with triangle drop down arrow?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, stroke

I need to create a spinner with rectangular border with triangle drop down arrow. How to create such spinner? I tried but my actual output difers from expected output.
Here is expected output.

[image]

But my output looks like this.

[image]

How to create a spinner with drop down image with rectangular box?

Here is my code which I applied.

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Preferred contact method">
        </TextView>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/account_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Telephone">
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

EditText border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000" />
```

But how to apply for spinner with triangle arrow and outer rectangle border?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It just renders like that in the XML layout preview because Preview doesn't know what data you want to bind to the spinner. It will look like a normal spinner with the drop down arrow once you run it on a device or emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look in the Android SDK folder at the existing background image for a dropdown. On example is located in `{sdk_folder}\platforms\android-{xx}\data\res\drawable-{density}\dropdown_normal_holo_dark.9.png`. It is just a matter of defining a so called 9-patch drawable and applying that to the style of your dropdown.

This explains how to create one such drawable (and also has a link to an explanation on what a 9-patch is): https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html